# Implementing the Show class

Tags: haskell

Suppose we have the following:

```
data Foo x
from_list :: [x] -> Foo x
to_list :: Foo x -> [x]
```

Suppose I want to declare `instance (Show x) => Show (Foo x)` such that showing a value produces the appropriate call to `from_list`. How *exactly* do I do that? In particular, how do I implement `showsPrec` so that the trixy fiddly precedence rules are satisfied? (That is, put the expression in brackets if and only if it's necessary.)

Comment: Not seeing any constructors defined, it's not clear what list you want to process with `from_list` when showing your `Foo x`. How it would relate to fields of Foo?

Comment: You don't need to define it with `showsPrec`. A minimal complete instantiation of `Show` is just `show`, and `showsPrec` will be defined in terms of it. The same mechanism allows only defining one of `(==)` and `(/=)` for `Eq` and get the other for free.

Comment: I'm going for something like <code>show foo = "Foo (fromList " ++ show (to_list foo) ++ ")"</code>, but using <code>showsPrec</code> and with correct precedence handling.

Comment: @danr <code>showsPrec</code> is more efficient.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid depends on how many appends you need to do. Your example above suggests that you are just appending and prepending constant strings to a call to `show` on a list, and that instance function is already efficient. But as Dmitry Dzhus points to, there is no reason to use `showsPrec` unless you show us some constructors and the intention behind `Foo`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want here is basically the same as [what `Data.Set` does](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/0.4.2.0/doc/html/src/Data-Set.html#line-721), so we can just modify that a little:

```
instance Show x => Show (Foo x) where
  showsPrec p xs = showParen (p > 10) $
    showString "from_list " . shows (to_list xs)
```

In other words, we use the `Show` instance for lists, prepend `"from_list "` to that, and use `showParen` to add brackets around it if the surrounding context has higher precedence than function application (which has precedence 10).

```
> show (from_list [1, 2, 3])
"from_list [1,2,3]"
> show (Just $ from_list [1, 2, 3])
"Just (from_list [1,2,3])"
```

Comment: In the second example: `show (Just $ from_list [1, 2, 3])` is it showing parantheses because `p` evaluates to `11`? Or what exactly will `p` be? And what is setting the `p`?